# Can't SWAP on Pancake Rooter with web3.py

Tags: blockchain, uniswap, web3.py, pancakeswap, binance-smart-chain

I try to make a function that calls swapExactTokensForTokens on pacakeswap v2 rooter. The approval is mined, so is the swap. But when i check on bscscan, the contract execution fails for the swap (not the approval)

Here is my function :

```py
    def swap_tokens(self, tokenA_address: str, tokenB_address: str, amount: int, min_return: int):
        # Get the contract interfaces for the tokens
        tokenA_abi = self.get_abi_from_bscscan(tokenA_address)
        tokenA = self.w3.eth.contract(address=tokenA_address, abi=tokenA_abi)

        # Approve the DEX to transfer token A
        approve_txn = tokenA.functions.approve(self.contract.address, int(amount * 10**18)).build_transaction({
            'from': self.account.address,
            'nonce': self.w3.eth.get_transaction_count(self.account.address),
            'gas' : 30000,
            'gasPrice' : int(self.w3.eth.gas_price * 1.2)
        })

        try :
            signed_txn = self.w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(approve_txn, private_key=self.private_key)
            self.w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
            
            # Wait for the transaction to be mined
            print("Waiting for approval to be mined...")
            self.w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(signed_txn.hash)
            print("Approval mined !")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error sending approval: {e}")

        # Define the path of the swap
        path = [tokenA_address, tokenB_address]

        # Define the parameters of the swap
        swap_params = {
            'amountIn': int(amount * 10**18),
            'amountOutMin': min_return,
            'path': path,
            'to': self.account.address,
            'deadline': int(time.time()) + 15 * 60,
        }

        # Execute the swap
        swap_txn = self.contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(**swap_params).build_transaction({
            'from': self.account.address,
            'nonce': self.w3.eth.get_transaction_count(self.account.address),
            'gas' : 30000,
            'gasPrice': int(self.w3.eth.gas_price * 1.2)
        })

        try: 
            signed_txn = self.w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(swap_txn, private_key=self.private_key)
            self.w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
            
            # Wait for the transaction to be mined
            print("Waiting for swap to be mined...")
            self.w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(signed_txn.hash)
            print("Swap mined !")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error sending swap: {e}")
```

Where self.contract is a contract object (pancake rooter).
The get abi from bscscan is working, the approval is validated on the blockchain. The program also prints me that the swap is minned, but on bscscan, it fails :

[image]

And i don't know why ^^'

Ty to those who can help me ;)

Comment: Can be a lot of things like insufficient gas. Can you add your contract on Tenderly and see a deeper debug?